# Terminal command to show lines of a text file n characters long?

Tags: printing, file-management, grep

Is there a way to output only the content of lines in a text file that are 'n' characters long?

Ex: 1.txt

```
a
aa
aaa
aaaa
aaaaa
```

"Print lines(5)" would return "aaaaa"

Maybe some grep magic can do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

`grep -P '^.{n}$' filename`

Where `n` is the length you want, and `filename` is the target file

Comment: I believe that works, yet when I'm running it I get "grep: invalid UTF-8 byte sequence in input"

Anyway around that?

Comment: Do you get the same error if you use `--perl-regexp` instead of `-P`?

Comment: Yup, same error

Comment: How about `-E` instead of `-P`?  `-E` has the same result as `-P` for me on my machine

Comment: That generated "Binary file zzz.txt matches "

Not an issue now, I just changed the format of the text file I was working with to work with your solution.

Your answer is a solid one, it's just my file giving it problems. Thank you!